# Correct to use two methods to perform a similar task

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods

I am just looking to see if I am coding this the best way possible.

I have a classes Player, Pet, and Health.. Player has a feedPet method which calls the Pets method and then calls the setFeed method in the Health class.

In the setFeed method I adjust the health according to what the pet was fed. It also checks if the Pet is full, and then passes the adjusted hunger level to the setHunger method which simple sets the hunger equal to the hungerLevel argument.

Now the pet also has a method getHungry, if the pet isn't fed it has to get hungry right. What I have done here is access the pets health class and called the setNotFed method, here it calculates the appropriate hunger level of the pet and then passes that level to the setHunger method.

Is this the most correct way of doing this? I had thought of putting the setFeed and setNotFeed functionality into the setHungry method but that gets messy and confusing.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have a rule that the third time I write essentially the same code I'll turn it into a common function.  Only two similar methods doesn't bother me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your setHunger method in the Pet class? Perhaps it would be better suited in the Health class. Although it is true hunger is sensibly a property of the "Pet", if you have a "Health" class for the Pet, it may be better organized there. This depends if "Health" is supposed to specifically represent something like "damage", and maybe more specifically externally-caused damage, or anything that would be classified as "life signs", for lack of a better term. I imagine organization of most of the pertaining methods will fall into place if you do this. But since you came here for an *answer*...

When you learn (object-oriented) programming, you learn how to organize classes/methods based on their purpose, but in real life it gets more complicated...

- I'd say your Player class is good. The feedPet method is perfect there.
- It may seem contradictory, but it's not: the getHungry method should be part of Pet, as it is, as it is a *behavior*, while the hunger (pertaining to its *health*) is a field of Health. So...
- setNotFed and Hunger are mutators of hunger field(s), and belong where they are (in Health)

I think that's everything. Again, I recommend that Pet behaviors and actions done-by or -to the pet belong in pet, and anything modifying that which pertains to the Pet's "Health" is fit in the actual Health class.

I RECOMMEND YOU LOOK AT THE MINECRAFT.JAR DECOMPILED AND EXPLORE THE CLASSES! They are coded well and easily navigable, and lots of the stuff I bet your doing is right there in its own form! I based my answer on what I remember seeing while examining this!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, setHunger is a method in Health, and getHungry and eat are methods of pet. Good answer though thanks for confirming a few things with me. I will check out this minecraft jar. Not sure what you mean by the last bit there "in its own form?"

Comment: I was skimping on my English there, heh. I meant it's a game that's doing something of the same principles you are, no matter what style the game is (let's say given that Minecraft is a 3D sandbox game with pets with a similar system, you might be making a browser client side-scroller, but it still applies, even though they're 2 different "forms"). That's all I meant. Glad I could help! Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Cheers for the confirming you comment, Iv had a search for this minecraft jar and there are few of them around, not sure whats safe and whats not can you recommend one to me ?

Comment: Well, if you're familiar with the game Minecraft it can be really fun (modifying the code that is). I think there's a way to play it free...anyway that's not necessary. You can download the .jar for free and follow decompiling tutorials. It's easy.
I recommend: 
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/195813-creating-modsmodding-tutorials-absolute-beginner-9311/#entry2987480 for the tutorial, or even easier
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExXDkeUcO6M
Vid includes the eclipse workspace (which I think is generated as a result of MCP decompiling the .jar). Opens-up right in eclipse ready to examine!

Comment: Have you looked at the .jar yet? I'd like to know where you getting with this, it sounds cool.